# How to use ajax jquery in module of joomla 1.5

Tags: php, jquery, joomla1.5

I have a struct folder:

```
modules/mod_test/tmpl/default.php
modules/mod_test/tmpl/nation.php
modules/mod_test/helper.php
modules/mod_test/mod_test.php
modules/mod_test/mod_test.xml
```

in default.php I am using:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.nation').change(function(){
        var id = $(this).val();
        var dataString = 'id='+id;
        var url = 'modules/mod_test/tmpl/nation.php?'+dataString;
        $.getJSON(url + '&jsoncallback=?', function(data){
            $('.city').html(data);
        })
        return false;
   }); 
});
</script>
```

I has created nation.php in folder modules/mod_test/tmpl/ ? That right put in joomla ? And if right, How to call connect database in city.php that use ? How to ideas

Comment: Check this - > http://slacklabs.be/joomla-15/tutorial-creating-an-ajax-joomla-15-newsticker-module-with-jquery/page-2

Answer (score 0):

i guess you dont need `'&jsoncallback=?'` the function itself is callback function

```
$.getJSON(url, function(data){
         $('.city').html(data);
  })
```

This is internally equivalent to

```
$.ajax({
  url: "url",
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(data){
   $('.city').html(data);
  }
});
```